# Sencha touch 2 setActiveItem main view error

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am implementing a sliding navigation. When one of the list items in the slide navigation is clicked, I'm using the following controller code to load the relevant view:

```
switch(index){
    case 0: 
        this.getMain().setActiveItem({xtype:'main'});
        break;
    case 1: 
        this.getMain().setActiveItem({xtype:'messagesview'});
        break;
    case 2:
        this.getMain().setActiveItem({xtype:'articleslistview'});
        break;
    case 3:
        this.getMain().setActiveItem({xtype:'categoriesview'});
        break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Every one of those setActiveItem function calls work except the first on.
When I try to set the Main view as the active view, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#doAdd] Adding a card to a tab
>   container without specifying any tab configuration

Answer (score 0):

```
this.getMain().setActiveItem(0);
```

The code above solved the problem